# Why don't I get the reversed string I expect from this method?

Tags: ruby, string, return-value

In the following program *(written in irb shell)* i call a method `hidden` of the class `Tester` that accepts 2 arguments both of them string and then returns a string after modifying them. I get an output which i don't expect.

*What i expect is:*

```
def hidden(aStr,anotherStr) # After the call aStr = suhail and anotherStr = gupta
  anotherStr = aStr + " " + anotherStr
  # After the above statement anotherStr = suhail gupta
  return aStr + anotherStr.reverse 
  # After the above statement value returned should be suhailliahusatpug
  # i.e suhail + "reversed string of suhailgupta"
  end

  # But i get suhailatpug liahus
```

---

*ACTUAL CODE:*

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > class Tester
1.9.3p194 :002?>   def hidden(aStr,anotherStr)
1.9.3p194 :003?>     anotherStr = aStr + " " + anotherStr
1.9.3p194 :004?>     return aStr + anotherStr.reverse
1.9.3p194 :005?>     end
1.9.3p194 :006?>   end
1.9.3p194 :007 > o = Tester.new
=> #<Tester:0x9458b80> 
1.9.3p194 :008 > str1 = "suhail"
=> "suhail" 
1.9.3p194 :009 > str2 = "gupta"
=> "gupta" 
1.9.3p194 :010 > str3 = o.hidden(str1,str2)
=> "suhailatpug liahus"
```

Why is that ? Is it a *different matter* in *Ruby* as compared to some other OOP language like *Java* ?

Comment: what is wrong with this question ? ! Care to mention that pleeeease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Problem

You don't have the string you think you do. Forget the method, just do it line-by-line:

```
# You passed these as parameters, so they're assigned.
aStr = 'suhail'
anotherStr = 'gupta'

# You re-assign a new string, including a space.
anotherStr = aStr + " " + anotherStr
=> "suhail gupta"

# You are concatenating two different strings.
aStr + anotherStr
=> "suhailsuhail gupta"

# You concatenate two strings, but are reversing only the second string.
aStr + anotherStr.reverse
=> "suhailatpug liahus"
```

This is all exactly as it should be.

#### The Solution

If you want "suhailatpugliahus" then you need to avoid reassigning a new value to *anotherStr*.

```
def hidden(aStr,anotherStr)
    aStr + (aStr + anotherStr).reverse
end  
hidden 'suhail', 'gupta'
=> "suhailatpugliahus"
```

Comment: @revolver there is no goal. I am asking why it is doing that way ? I don't expect it to do that way. will you please follow the comments in the function

Comment: _"This reverses anotherStr, and then appends that value to the un-reversed aStr. It's exactly what you're telling it to do."_ yes ! but then the value in anotherstr = "suhail gupta" and astr = "suhail" so it should reverse "suhail gupta" and append it to "suhail"